# Shared functionality in plugins and themes

Tags: plugins, functions, themes, customization

I recently started to develop plugins and themes and I found that I need to use several functions of on both.

Sometime I think about to check if function / class exist before declared as said on this post: [When to check if a function exists](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23374/when-to-check-if-a-function-exists)

But that is considered as bad practice. What is best practice to prevent conflicts and keep themes & plugin work independently without one themes / plugin installed?

Answer (score 12):

### Actions & Filters

The *imho* best way is to use an action to bring plugin functions into themes.

### Example #1

Here's a little plugin to test this.

```
<?php 
/** Plugin Name: (#68117) Print Hello! */
function wpse68117_print_hello()
{
    echo "Hello World!";
}
add_action( 'wpse68117_say', 'wpse68117_print_hello' );
```

Inside the theme:

```
<?php
/** Template Name: Test »Print Hello!« Plugin */
get_header();
// Now we call the plugins hook
do_action( 'wpse68117_say' );
```

### What now happens / The kool kid

This way we don't have to check the existence of a function, a file, a class, a method or maybe even a (don't do this!) global `$variable`. The WP intern global already takes this for us: It checks if the hook name is the current filter and attaches it. If it doesn't exists, nothing happens.

### Example #2

With our next plugin, we're attaching a callback function that takes one argument.

```
<?php 
/** Plugin Name: (#68117) Print Thing! */
function wpse68117_print_thing_cb( $thing )
{
    return "Hello {$thing}!";
}
add_filter( 'wpse68117_say_thing', 'wpse68117_print_thing_cb' );
```

Inside the theme:

```
<?php
/** Template Name: Test »Print Thing!« Plugin */
get_header();
// Now we call the plugins hook
echo apply_filter( 'wpse68117_say_thing', 'World' );
```

This time, we offer the user/developer the possibility to add an argument. He can either `echo/print` the output, or even process it further (in case you got an array in return).

### Example #3

With the third plugin, we're attaching a callback function that takes two arguments.

```
<?php 
/** Plugin Name: (#68117) Print Alot! */
function wpse68117_alot_cb( $thing, $belongs = 'is mine' )
{
    return "Hello! The {$thing} {$belongs}";
}
add_filter( 'wpse68117_grab_it', 'wpse68117_alot_cb' );
```

Inside the theme:

```
<?php
/** Template Name: Test »Print Alot!« Plugin */
get_header();
// Now we call the plugins hook
$string_arr = implode(
     " "
    ,apply_filter( 'wpse68117_grab_it', 'World', 'is yours' )
);
foreach ( $string_arr as $part )
{
     // Highlight the $thing
     if ( strstr( 'World', $part ) 
     {
         echo "<mark>{$part} </mark>";
         continue;
     }
     echo "{$part} ";
}
```

This plugin now allows us to insert two arguments. We can save it into a `$variable` and further process it.

### Conclusion

With using filters and actions you're giving better performance by avoiding unnecessary checks (compare speed of `function_*/class_*/method_*/file_exists` or the search for a global with `in_array()` for ~1k(?) filter searches). You also avoid having all those unnecessary Notices for not set variables, etc., as the plugin cares about this.

Comment: Great insight on a best practice topic!

Comment: Thanks kaiser, you come with the best possible best practice for this issues. thanks again!

Comment: btw, we need to give different name for same functionality shared between plugin & themes right?

Comment: let say i have function i call jlog that will do simple wrapping pre to variable and print content of those variable. 
i add jlog function on themes and plugin, how can i prevent any conflict?

Comment: @JegBagus Have you really read the answer and tried the examples? The "Print Thing!" plugin is what you're after.

Comment: hi @kaiser yes sure, i actually already implement those method to easier extend (child themes) on my current themes. But i still don't get if we encounter my current case. let say i have 2 method on themes & plugin. they should able to work independently. Easiest case is logging. i create 1 function called jlog. both have those function. how can i implement those hook method to prevent conflict. and they need to keep run independently. i would thank you if you give me some short example directly for my case. Thank you so much kasier!

Comment: @JegBagus You are a very confused man :) Please update your question with the exact functions and explain what they are doing and _where_ they should be doing something. And please clean up your comments here. Thanks.

Comment: @kaiser Thanks for the answer. I got the gist. Thanks a ton.