# add_action failed to display function by a plugin

Tags: hooks, actions

I am using a plugin which has the following function: See end of question.

And I've created a hook in my template file:

```
<?php custom_hook(); ?>
```

And this is what I have in my functions.php

```
function custom_hook() {
    do_action('custom_hook');
    echo 'Custom Hook works!';
}

add_action('custom_hook', 'wnw_overall_rating_comments', 1);
```

I am curious, as why this isn't loaded. I have even edit the add_action to the plugin to see if my filter works,

```
add_action('custom_hook','wnw_overall_rating_comments');
```

But no luck.

Am I missing something here?

```
add_action('the_content','wnw_overall_rating_comments');
function wnw_overall_rating_comments($content)
{
    global $post,$rating_table_name,$wnw_multi_rating_table,$multi_rating_image_on,$multi_rating_image_off,$multi_rating_image_half,$wpdb;

    if($post->type != 'page')
    {
        //some function

        }
        return $content.$rating_value;
    }else
        return $content;    

}
```

Comment: [This answer explains how you should work with hooks/filters and themes/plugins](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/68117/shared-functionality-in-plugins-and-themes/68118#68118). In short: Does the string from `custom_hook` then `echo` in your template? Btw: The `add_action()` call _should_ reside in your plugin. Not in the theme.

Comment: You are adding to `custom_hook` in one code snippet and `the_content` in another... So which one is it?

Comment: Dear @kaiser, thank you for the article. I have been reading and trying different method to solve this. And following the Example 1.

What I do now is adding this on the theme file
`<?php do_action('custom_hook'); ?>`

And add the action `add_action('custom_hook','wnw_overall_rating_comments');` on the plugin.

That didn't work as it should. I'm trying to understand why it didn't pulled.

Comment: Because you need to `echo`... And please answer @Rarst question. Thanks.

Comment: @Rarst What I am trying to do is to pull the function from the plugin and execute it elsewhere in the theme. 

The current situation, the plugin execute the code at the `the_content` and I want it to execute at the `custom_hook`

But which bit should I echo as you suggest? Pardon my lack of knowledge.

Comment: After a bit more reading, I have managed to get what I want by adding the `echo` for the `return $content.$rating_value`

And the hooks is working fine now. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You're simply missing the `return print` or `echo` statement (instead of just `return`).